# Show new countdown timer after the previous countdown timer ends

Tags: javascript, html

This is an example of my current code, it shows you the current subject on a specific time and shows you when it's break.

However, I want to add a countdown timer on the next class.

For example, 1st class started at 8AM and next class is 10AM, a countdown timer will show below on the next class and as soon as it reaches 2nd class, it will show next countdown timer on the 3rd class.

```
<h1 id="subject"></h1>

<script>

var myDate = new Date();   

/* Time is 8AM */
if ( myDate.getHours() == 8 )  { 
 document.getElementById('subject').innerHTML ="1st Subject: English";  } 

/* Time is 10AM */
else if ( myDate.getHours() == 10 )  { 
 document.getElementById('subject').innerHTML ="2nd Subject: Math"; } 
 
 /* Time is 1PM */
else if ( myDate.getHours() == 13 )  { 
 document.getElementById('subject').innerHTML ="3rd Subject: Science"; }

else 
    {   document.getElementById('subject').innerHTML="Take a break!"; }
 
 
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the user should see -- let's say at 9.30? Just write the example in plain HTML.

Comment: user should see for example: 1st Subject: English - 1hr 29mins before next class